# How to use dplyr's summarize(across( )) when the function returns a list and the data is grouped

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr's summarise(across()) with the MannKendall function (returns a list). I have no problem using it if I don't use group_by() but when I do I get an error. This is my code:

```
Preds %>% group_by(Municipality) %>% 
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric),~list(MannKendall(.) %>%tidy %>% select(p.value, statistic)))) %>%
   pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
   unnest(c(value))
```

Error: Can't combine `Municipality`  and `Yield` .
Yield is one of my variables and it is numeric
This works but is not what I need:

```
Preds %>%  
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric),~list(MannKendall(.) %>%tidy %>% select(p.value, statistic)))) %>%
   pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
   unnest(c(value))
```

**For a reproducible example**:

```
iris %>%
   group_by(Species) %>%
   summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), ~list(MannKendall(.) %>%tidy %>% select(p.value, statistic)))) %>%
   pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
   unnest(c(value))
```

I think the problem is in trying to tidy the resulting dataframe containing lists in each column

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you! I realized the problem is in the tidy part. This works Preds %>% group_by(Municipality) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric),~list(MannKendall(.))) so it is just a matter of "tidying up" the resulting dataframe where all the columns contain lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unnest_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/hoist.html):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(Kendall)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), ~list(
    MannKendall(.) %>% 
      tidy %>% 
      select(p.value, statistic)))) %>%
  unnest_longer(Sepal.Length) %>%
  unnest_longer(Sepal.Width)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    Sepal.Length$p.value $statistic Sepal.Width$p.value $statistic
  <fct>                     <dbl>      <dbl>               <dbl>      <dbl>
1 setosa                   0.926     -0.0102               0.920    -0.0111
2 versicolor               0.0753    -0.178                0.400    -0.0859
3 virginica                0.750     -0.0326               0.226     0.124
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed